# POSTGRES IF statement fails

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to conditional statements within postgres. I have the following statement `SELECT IF status = 'L' THEN edate ELSEIF status = 'C' THEN 'wrong date' END IF as date FROM campaigns;`

But I get an error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "status" at character 11
LINE 1: SELECT IF status = 'L' THEN edate ELSEIF status = 'C' THEN '...
```

May I use it like this or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IF isn't part of SQL syntax, can't work. Use a CASE:

```
SELECT 
  CASE status
    WHEN 'L' THEN edate 
    WHEN 'C' THEN 'wrong date' 
  END as date 
FROM 
  campaigns;
```

Ps. If "edate" is of type DATE or TIMESTAMP, you have to cast this column to a VARCHAR because 'wrong date' is not a DATE nor TIMESTAMP.